# Making a J2ME Midlet sleep without threads?

Tags: java, java-me, scheduling, midlet, midp

Quick question ... Using J2ME (CLDC 1.1, MIDP-2.1) is it possible to sleep the Midlet for a period of time (not using threads)... For example:

```
public class myMidlet extends MIDlet{
    public void startApp() {
        /* Sleep for 10 seconds */

        /* The answer was: */
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time_ms);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
...
```

I don't use Java all that much, and don't want to program threads just for a simple sleep.

**Thanks in advance**

**Answer Summary**

My lack of Java knowledge. Examples I saw using Thread.sleep() led me to believe it was only usable in a thread object spawned by the Midlet ... not the midlet itself. I didn't want to have to spool off the midlet logic into a thread to sleep it ... But now I know the midlet runs in the default thread :) **Going to find that Java book I never read because I didn't think I would use the language ever**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't understand whether you mean putting midlet in paused state or just stopping execution for specified time.

If it's the latter, actually I don't undesrtand, why you don't want to use Threads, this is no big deal. You just insert three following lines wherever you need:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (Exception ex) {}
```

That's all, nothing too complicating.

Comment: Thanks :) Didn't occur to me that the MIDlet was executing as a main thread and therefore required Thread.sleep() ... The examples I saw online were used in spawned threads :S

Comment: Well, MIDlet is a normal Java application with main thread and everything. :) Method Thread.sleep() is static meaning it may be used anywhere. Just be careful if you use it in a thread, which is processing UI events (e.g commandAction() method of CommandListener).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact answer, but I also don't understand what's the problem with calling static method Thread.sleep(milliseconds) that "Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds" . Do you call this programming threads?

Comment: *slaps own head* Wasn't aware that the main thread was accessed like any other for sleeping (don't java much) ... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would go for Malcolm's approach since your thread may possibly throw an exception.

> [...]and don't want to program threads
>   just[...]

Uh, you'll have a hard time programming J2ME and trying to avoid threaded programming. If your app becomes just a bit more complicated, especially when using network connections you'll have to use threads. Moreover if some operation takes more than 2-3 seconds it's highly advisable to run it in a separate thread, possibly (contemporaneously) notifying the user about the ongoing work.

Btw, what I forgot. I've recently written a J2ME application for a university course. There I've constructed what I called "ExecutableTask" which allowed me to handle threads in a convenient and easy way. If you want to have a [look at the source](http://aroundj2me.googlecode.com)...Unfortunately you cannot browse it online in the Google repository due to some bug of Google's hosting solution (some name of my project my cause this).

Comment: Thanks Juri ... After trying it and getting the Uncaught exception thing I swapped accepted answer. Not trying to avoid threads ... it is just a simple app that I didn't realize had thread capability in the MIDlet :)

Comment: When I need a separate thread to avoid blocking main thread and I don't want to mess with new classes, I create an anonymous class which extends Thread and run it. Very convenient, especially in cases described by Juri: filesystem access or some network connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Object.wait()`, `Object.wait(long timeoutValue)`. Although I would not advise you to try and delay the main startApp() / system thread.